# Meteor #each loop ready

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I wonder is there any way to know if #each loop is "ready". By "ready" I mean it rendered all nodes and inserted into the DOM. I don't even speak about `onRendered` callback (old `rendered`). I tried

```
<template name="myTemplate">
<div class="some-class">
    {{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
       {{#each messages}}
          <div>{{text}}</div>
       {{/each}}
       <script>
           $(".some-class").trigger("LOOP_READY")
       </script>
    {{/if}}
</div>
</template>


Template.myTemplate.onRendered(function(){
    this.$(".some-class").on("LOOP_READY", doSomething)
})
```

But it does not work either. I don't want to use timers.

**UPDATE**

`messages` is a collection of text messages for current dialog, `dialogId` is a reactive var stored in the `Session`.

```
Template.myTemplate.onCreated(function(){
    var self = this;
    self.autorun(function(){
        self.subscribe("messages", Session.get("dialogId"))
    })
})
```

So if someone changes dialogId, myTemplate loads another dialog messages, and I want to know when this messages are ready, to scroll to a specific message. Simple `onReady` does not work, since I can not call scrollTop accurately before all messages are rendered and got its own height.

Comment: are you sure that `onRendered` together with a `waitOn` (see iron router) or similar doesn't work? I could imagine that the trigger that you see is from the first time the template renders, i.e., when no data is available yet. And I suspect that you want it only to trigger once the data has arrived and all the `each`'s have rendered. Do you wait for the data?

Comment: @ZuzEL can you explain why you want this? Do you need to initialize a plugin or something?

Comment: I think, if I get what you want, that your scrollToTop is firing before the new elements have been added. So technically, if you just hack and put the scrollToTop in a setTimeout(func,0) call, the elements height will be updated when you call scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@saimeunt provided elegant solution, but I implemented it other way, maybe someone find it helpful too.

Since I don't want my code been executed everytime a new message arrives, I can not trigger scrolling after autorun is finished. (You would say, OK, do it in autorun that depends only on `dialogId`. - then I can not get exact message count of this dialog since subscription should take some time)

HTML

```
<template name="myTemplate">
  <div class="chat">
    {{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
      <div class="messages">
          {{#each messages}}
            <div class="message">{{text}}</div>
          {{/each}}
      </div>
      <script>$(".chat").trigger("MESSAGES_READY_EVENT")</script>
    {{/if}}
  </div>
</template>
```

JS

```
Template.chat.onCreated(function () {
    var self = this;
    self.messages = function() {
        return Messages.find({dialogId:Session.get("dialogId")})
    }
    self.autorun(function(){
        self.subscribe("messages", Session.get("dialogId"));
    })
});
//helpers skipped
Template.chat.onRendered(function () {
    var self = this;
    self.$(".chat").on("MESSAGES_READY_EVENT", function () {
        var computationNumber = 0;
        var $messages = self.$(".messages");
        //how many massages we have to render
        var total = self.messages().count();
        //max tries
        var maxTries = 10;
        var intervalId = Meteor.setInterval(function () {
            var totalNodes = $messages.children().length;
            if (computationNumber++ >= maxTries || total <= totalNodes) {
                Meteor.clearInterval(intervalId);
                $messages.scrollTop(someValue);
            }
        }, 100);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy way to get notified when a Spacebars `{{#each}}` block has done rendering into the DOM every item its spanning.

The best solution is to use another reactive computation (`Tracker.autorun`) to observe your messages cursor changes.

Everytime your messages list is modified, you can run arbitrary code after every other reactive computations are done performing whatever their job is, using `Tracker.afterFlush`.

The `{{#each}}` block is one of those computations, whose role is to listen to the reactive data source you give it as argument and rerender its `Template.contentBlock` as many times as items fetched from the source being iterated over, with the current item as current data context.

By listening to the exact same reactive data source as the `{{#each}}` block helper and running your code AFTER it has finished its own reactive computation, you can get the actual requested behavior without relying on some weird `setTimeout` tricks.

Here is the full implementation of this pattern :

HTML

```
<template name="myTemplate">
  <div class="some-class">
    {{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
      {{#each messages}}
        <div class="message">{{text}}</div>
      {{/each}}
    {{/if}}
  </div>
</template>
```

JS

```
// declare your reactive data source once to reuse the same in multiple places
function messagesCursor(){
  return Messages.find();
}

Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  messages: messagesCursor
});

Template.myTemplate.onRendered(function(){
  this.autorun(function(){
    // we need to register a dependency on the number of documents returned by the
    // cursor to actually make this computation rerun everytime the count is altered
    var messagesCount = messagesCursor().count();
    //
    Tracker.afterFlush(function(){
      // assert that every messages have been rendered
      console.log(this.$(".messages") == messagesCount);
    }.bind(this));
  }.bind(this));
});
```

Comment: Thank you, good solution. I will test this. I'm concerned that if computation is finished it does not mean that all elements already inserted into DOM. FYI, I implemented such behavior creating an interval in autorun function. See my answer.

Comment: OK, your answer is good, but since I don't want to scroll to a specific message everytime new message arrives, I can not use it. See my solution.