# Meteor onRendered - difficulty accessing DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I'm having trouble accessing the DOM from within a Template onRendered block in Meteor. Here is a simplified version of the template html:

```
<template name="templateName">
  {{#each thing}}
    <img src="{{filename}}">
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

And here is the client JavaScript code:

```
Template.templateName.onRendered(function() {
  console.log('check');
  this.$('img').each( function() {
    console.log('hi');
  });
});
```

I have verified that the code is running, as the 'check' appears in the browser console, but none of the 'hi's are printed despite several images displaying.

In case there is a better alternate way to go about this in general, the goal here is to resize images using information from the DOM.

To confirm, the jquery package is added to Meteor.

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide! I've been stumped for several hours on this deceptively simple issue.

Comment: Your problem is that at the time your `onRendered` handler is executed, your images are not yet rendered inside the DOM because the `{{#each}}` block helper has not yet executed its reactive computation. Check this detailed answer of mine about a similar problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30448656/meteor-each-loop-ready/30460712#30460712

Comment: Aha, thank you for this detailed explanation! Great explanation for why juliancwirko's solution works and the above code does not.

Comment: Follow up: I'm trying to get the (natural) width and height of the image within the onRendered function, but it's returning 0, indicating that while the template has rendered the images aren't yet loaded. How can I wait for the images to load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Follow up: I'm trying to get the (natural) width and height of the
>   image within the onRendered function, but it's returning 0, indicating
>   that while the template has rendered the images aren't yet loaded. How
>   can I wait for the images to load?

Completing @juliancwirko answer, now that you have a separate template for defining your images list items, you can listen to the load event on the `img` tag using Meteor event maps.

```
Template.imgTmpl.events({
  "load img": function(event, template){
    console.log("image width :",this.$("img").prop("width"));
    console.log("image height :",this.$("img").prop("height"));
  }
});
```

Comment: Aha, very interesting, didn't even think to use events! What happens if the image changes size (e.g. in a window resize event)? I'm using Boostrap and column widths can change from time to time.

Comment: If you want to track dynamically the size of the image on resize, setup a resize handler `$(window).on("resize",handler)` in your parent template `onRendered` lifecycle event and use standard jQuery to iterate over the template images and observe their `clientWidth` and `clientHeight` properties (they contain the actual on screen size taken by the images, not the underlying bitmap size).

Comment: Ok, playing around with that now. Thanks so much for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use jQuery `each` in your onRendered parent template. Instead you can do something like:

```
<template name="templateName">
    {{#each thing}}
        {{> imgTmpl}}
    {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="imgTmpl">
    <img src="{{filename}}">
</template>
```

js:

```
Template.templateName.onRendered(function() {
    console.log('check');
});

Template.imgTmpl.onRendered(function() {
    console.log('hi');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the very quick and helpful answer! Now the needed information is accessible. Out of curiosity, why does the jQuery `each` not work in the onRendered code?

Comment: Ah, saimeunt's answer answers the question here

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me:

```
Template.imgTmpl.events({
  "load img": function(event){
    console.log("width " + event.currentTarget.naturalWidth);
    console.log("height " + event.currentTarget.naturalHeight);
  }
});
```